# Newsletter Subscription Functionality in Codeigniter 3

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a **online newspaper/blogging application** with **CodeIgniter 3.1.8** and **Twig**.

The application is meant to offer developers and designers the possibility to very easily turn their HTML templates into database-powered websites. To achieve this, I used the **Twig** template engine, for the frontend.

I have recently added a **newsletter subscription** functionality.

The newsletter subscriptition form:

```
<h5>Sign Up for Newsletter</h5>
<p>Signup to get updates on articles, interviews and events.</p>
  <div class="subscribe-form">
    <div id="messags" class="is-hidden h-text-center">
      <div class="success is-hidden alert-box alert-box--success">You have successfully subscribed to our newsletter</div>
      <div class="notnew is-hidden alert-box alert-box--info">You are already subscribed</div>
      <div class="fail is-hidden alert-box alert-box--error">Sorry, the newsletter subscription filed</div>
    </div>
    <form name="newsletter" method="post" action="{{base_url}}newsletter/subscribe" id="newsletterForm" class="group" novalidate>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="email" value="{{set_value('email') | striptags}}" data-rule-required="true" placeholder="Your Email Address"> 
      <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="subscribe">
    </form>
</div>
```

The form data is submitted via jQuery Ajax:

```
(function($) {
    $("#newsletterForm").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                email: true
            }
        },

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var form = $("#newsletterForm"),
                $fields = form.find('input[type="email"]'),
                url = form.attr('action'),
                data = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#messags').slideDown(250).delay(2500).slideUp(250);
                    $fields.val('');
                    if (response.is_new_subscriber === true) {
                        $('#messags .success').show();
                        $('#messags .notnew').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#messags .notnew').show();
                    }
                },
                error: function() {
                    $('#messags .fail').show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The **Newsletter** controller:

```
class Newsletter extends CI_Controller {
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
    public function subscribe()
    {
        $data['is_new_subscriber'] = true;
        if (!$this->Newsletter_model->subscriber_exists()) {
            $this->Newsletter_model->addSubscriber();
        } else {
            $data['is_new_subscriber'] = false;
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

The **Newsletter_model** model:

```
class Newsletter_model extends CI_Model {
    
    public function subscriber_exists()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('newsletter', array('email' => $this->input->post('email')
        ));
        return $query->num_rows() > 0;
    }
    
    public function addSubscriber()
    {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'subscription_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
        return $this->db->insert('newsletter', $data);
    }
    
    public function getSubscribers()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('newsletter');
        return $query->result();
    }
    
    public function editSubscriber($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('newsletter', array(
            'id' => $id
        ));
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
        }
    }
    
    public function updateSubscriber($id)
    {
        $data = array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email')
        );
        
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->update('newsletter', $data);
    }
    
    public function deleteSubscriber($id)
    {
        return $this->db->delete('newsletter', array(
            'id' => $id
        ));
    }
}
```

The newsletter subscribers are managed in the back-end.

The view:

```
<?php if(count($subscribers)):?>
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-sm mb-0 w-100">
    <thead>
      <tr class="row m-0">
        <th class="w-5">#</th>
        <th class="w-50">Email</th>
        <th class="w-25">Subscription date</th>
        <th class="w-20 text-right">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($subscribers as $index => $subscriber): ?>
      <tr id="<?php echo $subscriber->id; ?>" class="row m-0">
        <td class="w-5"><?php echo $index + 1; ?></td>
        <td class="w-50"><?php echo $subscriber->email; ?></td>
        <td class="w-25"><?php echo $subscriber->subscription_date; ?></td>
        <td class="w-20 text-right">
          <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/subscribers/edit/' . $subscriber->id); ?>" title="Edit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a>
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard/subscribers/delete/' . $subscriber->id); ?>" title="Delete" class="delete-subscriber btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="text-center">No subscribers</p>
<?php endif ?>
```

The **Subscribers** controller (in the dashboard):

```
class Subscribers extends CI_Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
            
            if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
                redirect('login');
            } else {
                // Admin ONLY area!
                if (!$this->session->userdata('user_is_admin')) {
                    redirect($this->agent->referrer());
                }
            }

            $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
            $data['subscribers'] = $this->Newsletter_model->getSubscribers();

            $this->load->view('dashboard/partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/subscribers');
            $this->load->view('dashboard/partials/footer');
    }

        public function edit($id) {
            // Only logged in users can edit subscribers
            if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
                redirect('login');
            }
    
            $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
            $data['subscriber'] = $this->Newsletter_model->editSubscriber($id);
    
            $this->load->view('dashboard/partials/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('dashboard/edit-subscriber');
            $this->load->view('dashboard/partials/footer');
        }

        public function update() {
            // Only logged in users can update user profiles
            if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')) {
                redirect('login');
            }
    
            $id = $this->input->post('subscriber');
    
            $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
            $data['subscriber'] = $this->Newsletter_model->editSubscriber($id);
    
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error-message">', '</p>');
    
            if(!$this->form_validation->run()) {
                $this->load->view('dashboard/partials/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('dashboard/edit-subscriber');
                $this->load->view('dashboard/partials/footer');
            } else {
                $this->Newsletter_model->updateSubscriber($id);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('subscriber_updated', 'The email address was updated');
                redirect('dashboard/subscribers');
            }
        }

        public function delete($id) {
            if ($this->Newsletter_model->deleteSubscriber($id)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('subscriber_delete_success', "The subscriber was deleted");
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('subscriber_delete_fail', "Failed to delete subscriber");
            }
            redirect('dashboard/subscribers');
        }
}
```

My main concern is *security*, but I will appreciate *any constructive criticism*. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will share here my thoughts and personal opinions:

1. Use this array format `[]` and not `array()`
2. Instead of loading data and business logic inside the view (e.g subscribers list - `<?php if(count($subscribers)):?>`). Do everything on the backend and return the result as JSON to the fronted. This will give you more scalability and control. The PHP business logic in the view should be avoided and only JS should be used there.
3. Since you're using IDs in the URL (e.g. `public function edit($id)`), always check for the $id to be an integer and not null before the model

That's my opinions, maybe someone else can add something more :)

Comment: I prefer the array format `[]` (and have used I often), but **[this](http://www.phpformatter.com/)** PHP beautifier does not allow it. :(